# Open calculator on clicking textview

Tags: java, android, debugging

I want to open my made calculator after clicking on edittext field. I have written this code but it doesn't work

```
textOut1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetInput1);         
TextView.OnEditorActionListener(textout1,EditorInfo.IME_NULL,com.easyPhys.start.calculator);
```

It underlines everything what is in brackets. What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried an onFocusChange?  Maybe something like this:

```
textOut1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetInput1);         
textOut1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(hasFocus) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, calculator.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: with this it gives error:  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener) from the type View. I think I need to show ID somewhere. I just don't know where

Comment: @L.G. Sorry, it the second line should be

    textOut1.setOnFocusListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

instead of "TextView"

Comment: do I need to change anything in html file?

Comment: TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView exampleView, int actionId,KeyEvent event) {
if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL){
startActivity (new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator")); 
}return true;}};
textOut1.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
textOut2.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
textOut3.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
I have changed my code to be like this but that I get now is after hitting done it goes to the page I want, but how to do it before hitting enter?